# Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of nonzero numbers that converges to $\infty$. Prove that $\{1/x_n\}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am unsure if my proof is valid.
Edited Proof:
Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence of nonzero numbers that converges to $\infty$. This means for every M > 0 there exists a $ N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq N \Rightarrow x_n > M$. Then, $x_n >M \Rightarrow 1> M/x_n \Rightarrow 1/M > 1/x_n$. Choose N to be $ M = 1/\epsilon$ for any given $\epsilon >0$. Then $n \geq N \Rightarrow |1/x_n -0| = |1/x_n| = 1/x_n < 1/M < 1/1/\epsilon =\epsilon$. Thus {1/x_n} $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: $1>M/x_n  \Rightarrow 1/M > 1/x_n $ is the correct implication. You divide through by $M$. Choose an $N$ to $M:=1/\varepsilon$ for any given $\varepsilon>0$ by appealing to the original assumptions. I let you work out the details.

Comment: It is not $N$ but $x_n$ you want to be greater than $1/\varepsilon$, hence you should choose $N$ such that $n\geq N \Rightarrow x_n > 1/\varepsilon$.

Comment: Also, why bother proving that $1/x_n$ does not converge to $\infty$? This is an unnecessary argument and can be removed to make the proof simpler.